# Paypal: I haven't received any email

Tags: email, paypal, confirm

i want to test payment online by paypal, when i register from sandbox, it's require me confirm by email, but waiting so long i haven't received any email to confirm. So i can not request money to test my site. What wrong with me?

Comment: This is off topic here. Check your junk email box? Try again? setup a temporary gmail/hotmail/yahoo account?

Comment: gmail and yahoo .. and look at my question again "i haven't received any email"